# How to develop Hyperledger Fabric chaincode using Node js

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

As we know in Hyperledger Fabric we can develop chaincode using NodeJs. I have found most of chaincode tutorial which are providing the very simple example. Can anyone please suggest how to develop real-time chaincode using NodeJs like (Car auction).

I have found the chaincode for "Car auction" at [https://github.com/ITPeople-Blockchain](https://github.com/ITPeople-Blockchain/auction/blob/v1.1.0/art/artchaincode/art_app.go), but it is developed in "go-lang".

Please suggest how to develop the same chain code in NodeJs.

Comment: Anyone have any complex example of chaincode in NodeJs. Please share it. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-node explains the basics of how to work with Node.js chaincode and https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release-1.1/fabcar has the option to use Node.js chaincode ( https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release-1.1/chaincode/fabcar/node )

Comment: Thanks for your response,   But I have already covered all those links and in that fabcar chaincode it explains very simple scenario. I need to know how to develop chaincode for complex scenario like: having multiple participants and multiple asset.